# Prepend Kernel module function globally

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, mri

I want to prepend `Kernel.rand` like this:

```rb
# I try something like

mod = Module.new do
  def rand(*args)
    p "do something"

    super(*args)
  end
end

Kernel.prepend(mod)
```

```rb
# And I expect this behaviour

Kernel.rand            #> prints "do something" and returns random number
rand                   #> prints "do something" and returns random number
Object.new.send(:rand) #> prints "do something" and returns random number
```

Unfortunately, the code above does not work as I want to. Prepending `Kernel.singleton_class` does not work too

It's not required to use `prepend` feature, any suggestiion that will help to achieve the desired behaviour is welcome

Comment: In addition to the expected behavior, you might want to add you code's actual (unexpected) behavior / output.

Comment: BTW, what is your actual use case, i.e. why do you want to patch `Kernel.rand` in the first place?

Comment: Basically I want to track every `rand` invocation. Looks like simply upgrading to Ruby 3.2 fixed the issue and now I obraint expected results

Comment: Keep in mind that beside `Kernel.rand`, there's also [`Random.rand`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.3/Random.html#method-c-rand), [`Random#rand`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.3/Random.html#method-i-rand) and (via stdlib) also [`SecureRandom`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.3/SecureRandom.html)'s `rand`.

Comment: I was using v2.7 and wasn't aware of the change made in v3.0, which is why I deleted my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Kernel` methods like `rand` or `Math` methods like `cos` are defined as so-called *module functions* (see [`module_function`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.3/Module.html#method-i-module_function)) which makes them available as both,

... (public) singleton methods:

```
Math.cos(0)  # <- `cos' called as singleton method
#=> 1.0
```

... and (private) instance methods:

```
class Foo
  include Math

  def calc
    cos(0)   # <- `cos' called from included module
  end
end

foo = Foo.new

foo.calc
#=> 1.0

foo.cos(0)   # <- not allowed
# NoMethodError: private method `cos' called for #<Foo:0x000000010e3ab510>
```

To achieve this, `Math`'s singleton class doesn't simply include `Math` (which would turn all its methods into singleton methods). Instead, each "module function" method gets defined twice, in the module and in the module's singleton class:

```
Math.private_instance_methods(false)
#=> [:ldexp, :hypot, :erf, :erfc, :gamma, :lgamma, :sqrt, :atan2, :cos, ...]
#                                                                  ^^^

Math.singleton_class.public_instance_methods(false)
#=> [:ldexp, :hypot, :erf, :erfc, :gamma, :lgamma, :sqrt, :atan2, :cos, ...]
#                                                                  ^^^
```

As a result, prepending another module to `Math` or patching `Math` in general will only affect the (private) instance method and thus only classes including `Math`. It won't affect the `cos` method which was defined separately in `Math`'s singleton class. To also patch that method, you'd have to prepend your module to the singleton class, too:

```
module MathPatch
  def cos(x)
    p 'cos called'
    super
  end
end

Math.prepend(MathPatch)                 # <- patch classes including Math
Math.singleton_class.prepend(MathPatch) # <- patch Math.cos itself
```

Which gives:

```
Math.cos(0)
# "cos called"
#=> 1.0
```

As well as:

```
foo.calc
# "cos called"
#=> 1.0
```

However, as a side effect, it also makes the instance method public:

```
foo.cos(0)
# "cos called"
#=> 1.0
```

I've picked `Math` as an example because it's less integrated than `Kernel` but the same rules apply to "global functions" from `Kernel`.

What's special about `Kernel` is that it's also included into `main` which is Ruby's default execution context, i.e. you can call `rand` without an explicit receiver.

Comment: Alright, I finally got it working. Here's why it didn't work before

Basically I was doing this

```ruby
mod = Module.new do
  def rand(*args)
    p "..."

    super(*args)
  end
end

[Kernel, Kernel.singleton_class].each { _1.prepend(mod) }
```

And it just didn't work as expected in MRI 2.7.4
Hovewer, it works as expected in Ruby 3.2.3. So I quess they changed something in ruby implementation

Comment: @vetements in Ruby 2.7.4 you have to `include` / `prepend` _before_ the module gets included. Starting with Ruby 3.0, changes to the ancestors list(s) will be applied retroactively.

Comment: thanks for telling! I remember reading in "Ruby under a microscope" book about this, but I didn't know it was fixed in Ruby  3.0